# Adding a System.Threading.Timer to a windows service in VS 2010

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-services, timer

This is my first time working with windows service, and I am learning as I go.
I am using VS 2010, Windows 7 to create a windows service that will have a timer. I have googled and browsed this site as well [Use of Timer in Windows Service](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5495842/788487), [Best Timer for using in a Windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/q/246697/788487) but I still am confused as to where to code for the timer in the windows service component

I have an OnStart method and OnStop method in the service1.cs class
Where would I code for the timer to execute the function (NOT start the windows service)?

Comment: Are you actually talking about *starting* the service or periodically executing some functionality *within* your service?

Comment: Periodically executing the function within the service

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below is an example of how to do this.  It writes a message to the Application log (as seen in the Event Viewer) every 10 seconds until the service is stopped.  In your case, put your periodic logic in the OnElapsedEvent() method.

```
private System.Timers.Timer _timer = new System.Timers.Timer();

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    _timer.AutoReset = true;
    _timer.Interval  = 10000;  // 10 seconds
    _timer.Elapsed  += OnElapsedEvent;
    _timer.Start();
}

protected override void OnStop()
{
    _timer.Stop();
}

private void OnElapsedEvent(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    // Write an entry to the Application log in the Event Viewer.
    EventLog.WriteEntry("The service timer's Elapsed event was triggered.");
}
```

I've got a couple of detailed answers here at SO that might be of help as you start working with Windows services.

- [Creating a Windows service using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593454/easiest-language-for-creating-a-windows-service/593803#593803)
- [How to have your service install/uninstall itself without using InstallUtil.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593454/easiest-language-for-creating-a-windows-service/593803#593803)

Answer (score 4):

Would it be easier to use a scheduled task to run a little console application or similar instead of dealing with the various nuances a Windows Service can bring?

If not, you may need to review a normal article on writing windows services such as [this c# article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/simplewindowsservice.aspx) or [this VB Article](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/3441/creating-a-windows-service-in-vbnet/).  Once you see how a normal service runs (a service that doesn't use a timer), you should know where to add in the timer code.

Hope that helps?

Comment: Scheduled Tasks that run for several hours (9 hours in my case) seem to be cut off short. Not sure if a bug in code or a problem with Task Scheduler. But this alternative will be helpful. Ops here where I work is good with either or. But they might be a deciding factor.

Comment: @TamusJRoyce 4 year old thread; let me know if you have any questions (or better, same username on twitter). Good luck.