# Save File Using Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a Windows Service consisting of a timer with 4000 Interval, in tick method of timer a save method run and save a bitmap file in specific path, it is like the following:

```
 protected override void OnStart(string[] args) {
        CaptureTimer.Start();
    }

private void CaptureTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        Bitmap capture = Capture.GetImage();
        capture.Save(@"D:\Doc\Temp\GeoServiceFiles\" + Environment.MachineName +
        dt.Ticks.ToString() + ".bmp");
    }
```

but there is not any saved file, I test the exact code in Win Application and that worked correctly replaced OnStart method with button1_Click. also for test my service add an eventlog: `eventLog1.WriteEntry("test service");` and log saved correctly but yet there isn't any saved file, So is there any special way to saved files with Windows Services?

Comment: It is amazing to me how many people on this site are creating Windows Services that draw/save bitmap images. I can't really think of very many applications for this, but I see an average of 2-3 questions per day on the subject!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use of Timer in Windows Service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495842/use-of-timer-in-windows-service)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Timer you use? I think you must use `System.Threading.Timer` look at this [Use of Timer in Windows Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495842/use-of-timer-in-windows-service)

Comment: Also, why is the OP asking himself a question in this answer...?

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked the permissions on the folder `D:\Doc\Temp\GeoServiceFiles\`?

The windows service usually run as Local System, Network Service or similar depending on how you set it up, but it will not have the same rights as the win application you run as your own user.

Try setting the folder to Full control for Everyone just to check that it works, and refine the permissions afterwards if that is the source of the problems.

Comment: I use Local System in Account property, and the folder doesn't any special permission is there any other settings that must be checked?

Comment: Have you tried setting Full control for Everyone and then running the service? By default Local System services does not have permission to save files iirc

Comment: How can Set Full Control to Everyone?

Comment: Right click folder, click properties, go to security tab, click edit, click Add, write Everyone and click Ok. Select Everyone from the list, put a checkmark in Full control -> Allow. Click ok to close the permissions window, and ok to close the properties window.

Comment: I do Exactly as you said but not work, there isn't any Saved Files.

Comment: Saeid - It was worth a try anyway ;)

Comment: I have the same issue... I have also changed what user the service uses, to Administrator and other things, but the file never appears anywhere. If I install the service on mu local computer, and tell it to write a file to C:\bla.txt, then I see an exception in the Event Viewer. But when I put the same code on a server elsewhere, then there is no exception in the Eventview, and no files created .